What is the simplest approach to implement a controlled lexical.js editor in react?
I want to implement a component that uses a dynamic number of lexical editors in React. These editors should have an initial text content. When the users finishes adding editors and content, they should be able to submit the text content of all the editors.
I tried with this approach, but I ran into infinite loop issues when trying to dynamically set the number of editors and their ids.
